# Why doesn't Excel Interop support Watches in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, excel-interop

I'm debugging some code that uses `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;`

On any variable, no matter its nature or complexity, the debugger is completely unable to grab its value.
Let's say I have this code :

```
for (int i = 1; i <= myWorksheet.Range["MY_RANGE"].Rows.Count; i++)
{
   var tempValue = cells[i, 1].Value2;
}
```

I can add a watch on the expression `tempValue` but the expression `cells[i, 1].Value2` in a Visual Studio watch yields

> error CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Value2' and no accessible extension method 'Value2' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Although the execution works fine, and `tempValue` has a value.

`cells[i,1]` is of type `{System.__ComObject}`. Any of its properties throw the CS1061 error.

This is very frustrating because I cannot observe the value of any variable unless it's specifically executed in the code (I cannot get it through the watch).

Any idea why I cannot observe those values through a watch ? I suspect this is VS-based ..

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio under Tools-->Options-->Debugging enable the option "Use Managed Compatibility Mode".